# "nous tiendra lien" ?

Tags: grammaire

I have encountered in the transcription of a text

> nous tiendra lien

but is it not

> nous tiendra lieu ?

Does "nous tiendra lien" have a sense?

Comment: Can you paste the whole sentence ? Without that, it is impossible to give a relevant answer.

Comment: @Greg I have a feeling that "nous tiendra lien" may be an archaic locution. https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1DIMA_enFR786FR786&biw=1536&bih=722&tbm=bks&ei=g2HsXpqeOYmflwTetrso&q=%22nous+tiendra+lien%22&oq=%22nous+tiendra+lien%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...80479.84942.0.85976.2.2.0.0.0.0.83.124.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.nwsLNF-YMCk

Comment: @Dimitris: most of those hits in Google seem to be OCR mistakes for *tiendra lieu*.

Comment: Correct, those are OCR mistakes. The original is "nous tiendra lieu" (you can see it in the original text).

Comment: Minims are often a factor in transcription errors.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minim_(palaeography)#/media/File:Minims_(palaeography).jpg

Answer (score 2):

"Nous tiendra lien" does not have any sense in our current French. I checked some document and I  did not see "Nous tiendra lien"; maybe it's archaic French, but I don't think so.

Comment: Welcome to FSE. I edited your answer. Attention we write French, English, etc. (contrary to français, anglais, etc). Also, first personal pronoun ('je') is written with capital 'I'. When one writes contracted forms, e.g. for do not, there is need of an apostrophe. That is, don't.

Answer (score 1):

After querying a perfect matching search, we can find this book that uses something looking like a really old French.

> [Sermons pour tous les jours du caresme](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Wc8Tqt6AQjsC&pg=PA300&lpg=PA300&dq=%22nous%20tiendra%20lien%22&source=bl&ots=HdcCaLdLKl&sig=ACfU3U3rUh-IXM3PVR4eJ0_Z7b7t5HF5sQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSvdaF4JPqAhUqxYUKHVQADCQQ6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22nous%20tiendra%20lien%22&f=false) (looks like a religious book)

I think I could be used like 'nous retiendrons ...' or 'nous observons', I don't know an English translation that is really accurate but I think It might be 'we observe (something)' and 'we will mind(?) (something) ...'

but in this one :

> [Le Poète supposé, ou les Préparatifs de fête : comédie en trois actes](https://books.google.fr/books?id=NNUj1aKuJQUC&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=%22nous%20tiendra%20lien%22&source=bl&ots=P0LwoKELum&sig=ACfU3U2Dns3m_Emz-u8pAblWNhSwvBCvmg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSvdaF4JPqAhUqxYUKHVQADCQQ6AEwAnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22nous%20tiendra%20lien%22&f=false) (a theatre piece I guess)

it's more like 'notre coeur nous en dira(?)' or (very long one) 'écoutons notre coeur, il saura nous guider'. so I think it really depends on the context.

But since it seems to be really old French it is kind difficult to find a modern equivalent. If someone knows an Old French specialist, it could be interesting to ask him the 'now a days' equivalent of it.

---

EDIT:

I really think it's like saying something.

Lafontaine, *Le Corbeau et le Renard* (the crawl and the fox) *1668* ([the complete text](http://www.la-fontaine-ch-thierry.net/corbrena.htm))

> The fox 'tint (...) ce language' (say something) to the Craw

, and in the first book

Antoine Michaelis *Sermons pour tous les jours du caresme* 1677 ([source](https://ccfr.bnf.fr/portailccfr/ark:/06871/0011980879))

> Chrysostome(?) 'tiendra lien' (remark) "d'une infinité Docteurs que je pourrais citer" (an infinite amount of Doctors that 'I' could list)

Comment: I've just thought something, 'nous tiendra lien' and especially 'nous tiendra' may be better known as 'lui tint (à peu près ce language)' from Lafontaine _Le corbeau et le Renard_, so it might actually be my second guess